# Re-wiring a light switch

Tags: wiring

The power source is from a receptacle to three lights. A switch was inserted in the box at the first light. Is it better to wire the switch between the power source and the first light? If not, how do you wire the switch into the same box as the 3 lights and power source? Pretty crowded in there.

Comment: You may just have too many wires in that box.

Comment: Can you post photos of the box?  Also, is it OK with you if the box sticks out from the wall?

Comment: Harper, my thoughts exactly; too many wires wire nutted together with a strong likelihood that not all were connecting. I put the switch in line and eliminated excess wiring and everything is working now.  Thank you.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, this is barn wiring. the box sticks out.  I fixed the problem by rewiring the switch that controls the lights.  This is a more efficient way to power the lights.  You were on the same track as Harper and me, I think.  The box was packed tighter than carry-on baggage.  Thanks.